# SQLAlchemy leaks memory

Tags: python, memory-leaks, sqlalchemy

The following code leaks memory on my system:

```
def test():
    for u in users:
        session.flush()
        some_list = u.some_list
```

Where `users` is defined as

`users = session.query(User).yield_per(500000)`

and `some_list` is defined in the User model as

```
some_list = relationship("SomeThing", backref="user")
```

As you can see, running `session.flush()` does not free the used memory. For that matter, neither does `del some_list` at the end of the loop. The memory leakage goes away if I remove the `some_list = u.some_list` line.

***EDIT***: as requested, here's the entire code of the relevant file. I do not think that it'll help much, as I can reproduce the problem with only the function `test()`, though.

```
from redis import Redis
from pottery import RedisDict
import json

from anime_db import generate_session, User

redis = Redis.from_url('http://localhost:6379')
toshokan = RedisDict(redis=redis, key='toshokan')

session = generate_session(User)
users = session.query(User).yield_per(5000)


users = users[200000:]

def process():
    c = 0
    for u in users:
        session.flush()
        if c % 10000 == 0:
            print('PROCESSED {} USERS'.format(c))
        c += 1
        al_db = u.animelist
        name = u.name
        if len(al_db) == 0 or name in toshokan:
            continue
        al = []
        for a in al_db:
            al.append((a.anime_id, a.status, a.num_watched, a.score))
        toshokan[name] = json.dumps(al)
        del al_db, name, al

def test():
    c = 0
    for u in users:
        session.flush()
        if c % 1000 == 0:
            print('something')
        c += 1
        name = u.name
        al_db = u.animelist
```

The relevant database models are defined as such:

```
class AnimeEntry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'list_entries_anime'

    uid = Column(Integer, Sequence('anime_list_entry_id_seq'), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    anime_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("anime.uid"), nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.uid"), nullable=False)
    status = Column(Integer)
    num_watched = Column(Integer)
    score = Column(Integer)
    added = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<AnimeEntry(uid='%s', title='%s', user='%s')>" % (self.uid, self.anime_id, self.user_id)

class User(Base):
    """A user entry."""
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    uid = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)

    joined = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    animelist = relationship("AnimeEntry", backref="user")
```

***EDIT***: Stopping the loop does not stop the memory usage, but running `users = []` afterwards does. So the issue is something related to the `session.query(User).yield_per(5000)`

Comment: Why do you think `session.flush()` would free memory? You need `session.expunge_all()` for that.

Comment: I was told elsewhere that flush() would work; it did not. Neither did expunge_all(), for that matter.

Comment: How are you observing that you're having memory leaks? What does the rest of your code do?

Comment: System memory use increases unchecked at a steady pace. The only code I'm running is the code in the above code sample. Interrupting that function clears out the memory.

Comment: I suspect you're simply not reaching `session.expunge_all()` for it to matter. You're running 500,000 individual queries to load the `some_list` relationship, one for each user, and not clearing anything out. Try decreasing it to 500.

Comment: That's not the case; the code works perfectly if I remove the `some_list = u.some_list` line, as I've said in the original post. Also, memory usage keeps gradually increasing indefinitely, even after all the users are loaded.

EDIT: also, I have a pretty good idea how much memory 500k users should consume; each "user" in this case consists of just a handful of numbers. It definitely shouldn't be anywhere close to 10GB of memory.

Comment: "memory usage keeps gradually increasing indefinitely, even after all the users are loaded" -- so you are able to observe the `for u in users` loop finish? And afterwards you end up with `10GB` (and increasing) memory usage, but this does not happen if you don't load the relationship? I'm sorry, but it still sounds like another part of your application is contributing to this. Can you try to distill the problem down to a single file that we can use to reproduce this?

Comment: I meant that the first yield_per finished querying, sorry. The code doesn't get much beyond a few tens of thousands of users looped through before I run out of memory; it doesn't even come close to hitting the 500k it'd need to hit before it'd request another set of users.

Comment: And yes, as far as I can tell this does not happen if I do not load the relationship, though it's hard to tell.

I'll post the entire file I'm working with above, though I can not give the related database.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the code you've posted. (Run it [here](https://repl.it/Jgbj/1). Type `main()` on the right side to run.) You'll need to either figure out the difference between the snippet I've posted and your code, or post a *self-contained* example (like I did) that exhibits your problem.

Comment: There's nothing more for me to post. You have the full code. I can notice numerous differences between your code and mine, for example that we use different databases (I'm working on a postgres database).

However I would like to *strongly* implore you to just stop posting. You've done nothing but consistently ignore parts of the opening post, not believe me when I said I provided enough code to duplicate the problem, etcetera. Talking with you is just repeating myself, which is time I'd rather spend on solving the problem, if you do not mind.

Comment: Honestly I do not understand how you expect me to make this any more self-contained. The code I've shown you reproduces the problem for me. What more information could I provide, even if I wanted to? It's not like I can just fork over my user database, for multiple reasons.

Comment: I understand this process is frustrating, but it is equally frustrating for me trying to guess your problem when I can't run your code. Self-contained simply means I can run your code and reproduce your problem. It does *not* mean just including all the code you *think* might be causing the problem. You can't include your data? Include a dummy data set that reproduces your problem. Using PostgreSQL? See if it reproduces with SQLite as well. These are valuable information to have, and you'll have better luck in getting help if you provide them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `yield_per()` was somehow causing unreasonable memory usage. I've replaced that bit of the code with the following:

```
def page_query(q):
    offset = 0
    while True:
        r = False
        for elem in q.limit(10000).offset(offset):
           r = True
           yield elem
        offset += 10000
        if not r:
            break

users = page_query(session.query(User))
```

Which works as one would expect. I still don't know why exactly yield_per was behaving the way it does; I've used it before and it behaved properly in that context.